# Why page_load is called twice in my web application?

Tags: visual-studio, frameset, pageload

I have already gone through some of the posts in many websites regarding page_load being called twice but my problem is little bit different from those.

My problem is with the landing page of my web application.

Initially in my website page_load for the landing page was getting called twice every time when it is loaded. Since my application is an upgraded one (from VS 2003 to VS 2005/2008), I commented the "this.load" event in InitializeComponent. Now it works fine, when user first logs in, into my web application. But then, whenever user navigates to this page from any other page in my application, page_load gets called twice.

Does anybody have any idea about why this could be happening. I tried to track the call stack for this, but VS 2008 was showing that this was getting called from external code.

Also, I am using frames in my web application. I wonder if this problem has anything to do with frames.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Regards,

Hari

Comment: Hi, I have also managed to get the exact call stack trace for the page_load event when it gets called twice.  I just wonder how a timer event (System.Threading._TimerCallback.PerformTimerCallback) is calling the page_load again in my web application.

System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ResumeStepsFromThreadPoolThread(System.Exception error) + 0x25 bytes 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.ResumeStepsWithAssert(System.Exception error) 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(System.IAsyncResult ar)

Comment: System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpAsyncResult.Complete(bool synchronous, object result, System.Exception error, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus status)  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule.PollLockedSessionCallback(object state) 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._TimerCallback.TimerCallback_Context(object state) 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(object userData)

Comment: mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._TimerCallback.PerformTimerCallback(object state)